# SQL Server: selecting a year of account based on a specific date and a date range

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I need to apportion some values to a financial year that begins on the 1st December and ends on the 30th November each year.

The rows that contain the value fields are in a table (TABLE A) that has a reference number and an incident date

Table A

ReferenceNumber,    Value, IncidentDate

1,       10.00, 01/12/14

2,        15.00, 10/05/13

3,     20.00, 14/10/13

TABLE A is the joined to TABLE B which also has the reference number and contains transactional data including a start date field. Each reference number may have several transactions with different start date values and the aim is to ensure the row selected from TABLE B is the one where the start date is the most recent start date before the incident date from table A

TABLE B

ReferenceNumber,    StartDate

1,     01/05/14

1,      01/05/15

2,     12/04/14

2,      12/04/15

3,     05/06/14

3,     04/06/15

TABLE C is a time table that apportions specific dates to financial years.

TABLE C
Date,      FinancialYear

30/11/14,  FY2013/14

01/12/14,  FY2014/15

I am trying to construct a query which joins table A to table B on the Reference number and incident date to start date as described above and then adds the FinancialYear value based on the start date from Table B.

I am struggling to get this to return the correct financial year.

In addition, the data quality is poor so there are many examples where the Incident date from table A is greater than the scope of the financial year selected based on the start date from table B.

I need to be able to return either the appropriate financial year based on start date or, failing that, the financial year corresponding to the incident date

Here is the code I currently have:

```
SELECT  a.ReferenceNumber,
        b.StartDate,
        c.FinancialYear
FROM    dbo.TableA a
        INNER JOIN dbo.TableB b
            ON a.ReferenceNumber = b.ReferenceNumber
                AND b.StartDate = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM dbo.TableB WHERE a.IncidentDateTime > StartDate AND ReferenceNumber = a.ReferenceNumber)
        INNER JOIN dbo.Calendar c
            ON rdc.PolicyStartDate = c.[Date]
```

Comment: Why exactly is there only 1 day between  2013-2014 and 2014-2015?

Comment: Are you hoping to address the poor data quality in your code?  If at all possible I would recommend correcting the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    a.ReferenceNumber,
    min(Value) as Value,
    min(IndicentDate) as IncidentDate,
    max(StartDate) as StartDate /* others are dummy aggregates but this one is not */
    'FY'
     + cast(year(dateadd(month, -11, min(IncidentDate))) as char(4))
     + '/'
     + cast(year(dateadd(month, -11, min(IncidentDate))) - 1999 as char(2)) as FY
from
    TableA a cross apply
    (
        select * from TableB b
        where b.ReferenceNumber = a.Reference.Number and b.StartDate < a.IncidentDate
    ) b
group by a.ReferenceNumber
```

Your fiscal year starts eleven months "late" so it's easy to determine where a date falls without a lookup.

```
year(dateadd(month, -11, <date>))
```

Getting it to match your "FY2013/14" format takes a little extra work but you could write little functions to do these kinds of calculations. By the way, the 1999 comes from adding 1 and subtracting 2000 to get a two-digit year value. Could use modulo 100 to make it generic beyond the year 2098 if that's important.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The OP states that the calendar and financial years to do not directly overlap.  Example, which FY does 2/12/14 fall in?

Comment: @destination-data Which is why the date is adjusted 11 months before stripping out a year.

Comment: 2/12/14 in dd/mm/yyyy format would fall into FY2014/15

Comment: Thank you Shawnt00, your solution works very nicely once I'd adjusted the display of the Financial Year string to match the required format. It seems I was making it more complicated than it needed to be with the 3rd table for the lookup.

Comment: No, FY2013 started on December 1, 2013 and your date falls in that year.

Comment: @Chris That's cool but I'm curious which part of it was wrong. I'll tweak the answer if necessary.

Comment: Sorry @shawnt00 you're right - this query does take the fy time shift nicy into account.

Comment: Thanks @destination-data. By the way it's also handy to shift by hours or minutes when you have work shifts and work "days" that don't logically begin/end at midnight. It's a lot easier than the complicated case expressions I usually see.

Comment: @shawnt00 There was nothing at all wrong with your code, it was just the required output string for the FY needed to have 'YOA' on the end (for Year of Account) as opposed to 'FY' at the start. I just changed the elements of the final field returned by the query around to provide this.

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions going in:

- IncidentDate and StartDate are datatype "DATE".  This should also work if they are DATETIME with all time values set the same.
- TableC contains a row for every possible date (which is what you implied). Another style would be {FinancialYear, FirstDate, LastDate}, and you'd join to this table using `between` in the `on` clause.
- I didn't quite get what you meant regarding "the data quality is poor". This query will pull back the desired IncidentDate and StartDate 
  (if available), allowing you to apply business logic to them.  My sample here is "if there is no applicable StartDate, base the FinancialYear on IncidentDate. (Replace those outer joins with inner joins if the data permits it.)
- Toss in parameters if you dont' want this data for all ReferenceNumbers.
- Check for syntax errors, I couldn't run and test this query.

(Note that "Date" is a confusing name for a column.)

```
WITH ctePart1 (ReferenceNumber, IncidentDate, ClosestStartDate)
 as (--  Data based on the join to "most recent prior StartDate"
     select
        ta.ReferenceNumber
       ,ta.IncidentDate
       ,max(tb.StartDate)
      from TableA ta
       left outer join TableB tb
        on tb.ReferenceNumber = ta.ReferenceNumber
         and tb.StartDate < ta.IncidentDate
      group by
        ta.ReferenceNumber
       ,ta.IncidentDate)
 select
    cte.ReferenceNumber
   ,cte.IncidentDate
   ,cte.ClosestStartDate
   ,isnull(tcStart.FinancialYear, tcIncident.FinancialYear)  FinancialYear
  from ctePart1 cte
   left outer join TableC tcStart
    on tcStart.Date = cte.ClosestStartDate
   left outer join TableC tcIncident
    on tcIncident.Date = cte.IncidentDate
```